# nesting functions into function

Tags: python, function

I want to make five inches, I have two functions created, axe() creates the axes of the game array and area() inserts "X" according to the specified coordinates.

```
fiveinches = []
def axe():
    for a in range(1, 10):
        x = []
        x.append(a)
        print("", a, end="")
    for b in range(1, 10):
        y = []
        if b == 1:
            y.append(b)
            print("\n", b, sep="")
        else:
            print(b)
def area():
    for i in range(1,10):
        temp = []
        for j in range(1,10):
            temp.append(" ")
        fiveinches.append(temp)

    fiveinches[n][m] = "X"
    for list in twins:
        for element in list:
            print(element, end="")
        print(end="\n")

print("there is a player with crosses")
n = int(input("Enter the coordinate X: "))
m = int(input("Enter the coordinate Y: "))

#axe() or area()
```

The problem is that I do not know how to couple these two functions now to get both of them plotted in one area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than have two functions that each print part of the output, it would be better to have a single function that prints the entire output. You can store a grid of characters at the global scope so it can be written to by user input and read from by the display function.

```
grid = [[' ' for x in range(10)] for y in range(10)]
for i in range(1, 10):
    grid[0][i] = str(i)
    grid[i][0] = str(i)

def display_grid():
    for row in grid:
        print("".join(row))

while True:
    for char in "XO":
        x = int(input("Enter x Coordinate."))
        y = int(input("Enter y Coordinate."))
        grid[y][x] = char
        display_grid()
```

Result:

```
Enter x Coordinate.3
Enter y Coordinate.3
 123456789
1
2
3  X
4
5
6
7
8
9
Enter x Coordinate.4
Enter y Coordinate.7
 123456789
1
2
3  X
4
5
6
7   O
8
9
```

---

If you absolutely must keep your functions exactly as they are*, then you're in for an uphill battle. Once you print data to the console, Python has almost no way of accessing or manipulating it. By the time `area` is executing, the output of `axe` may as well have fallen into a black hole.

Rather, that's how the *default* stdout file-like object behaves. We can swap out the print-to-console behavior with whatever we want; the built-in `io.StringIO` class, for instance, could silently capture the outputs of axe() and `area()`. Then we could combine them and print to the normal stdout.

You almost never want to actually do this. Capturing stdout is a strategy of desperation when the data is not retrievable any other way. You have complete control over your data, so there are a dozen other approaches you should try first. But since you asked:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import io
import sys
import itertools

@contextmanager
def capture_stdout():
    old_stdout = sys.stdout
    try:
        sys.stdout = io.StringIO()
        yield sys.stdout
    finally:
        sys.stdout = old_stdout

def combine(a,b):
    """combines two multiline strings."""
    results = []
    for line_a, line_b in itertools.zip_longest(a.split("\n"), b.split("\n")):
        result_line = []
        for char_a, char_b in itertools.zip_longest(line_a or "", line_b or ""):
            result_line.append(next((c for c in (char_a, char_b) if c is not None and c != " "), " "))
        results.append("".join(result_line))
    return "\n".join(results)


fiveinches = []
def axe():
    for a in range(1, 10):
        x = []
        x.append(a)
        print("", a, end="")
    for b in range(1, 10):
        y = []
        if b == 1:
            y.append(b)
            print("\n", b, sep="")
        else:
            print(b)
def area():
    for i in range(1,10):
        temp = []
        for j in range(1,10):
            temp.append(" ")
        fiveinches.append(temp)

    fiveinches[n][m] = "X"
    for list in fiveinches:
        for element in list:
            print(element, end="")
        print(end="\n")

print("there is a player with crosses")
n = int(input("Enter the coordinate X: "))
m = int(input("Enter the coordinate Y: "))
with capture_stdout() as axe_output:
    axe()
with capture_stdout() as area_output:
    area()

print(combine(axe_output.getvalue(), area_output.getvalue()))
```

Result:

```
there is a player with crosses
Enter the coordinate X: 2
Enter the coordinate Y: 8
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1
2       X
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I notice that the X doesn't quite line up with the axes - rather than being aligned with 8 on the left and 2 on the top, it's aligned with 2 on the left and 4.5 on the top. Perhaps you could modify `fiveinches[n][m] = "X"` so it places the character in the right position. But I promised not to change `area` beyond what was strictly necessary, so updating that line is up to you ;-)

(*other than changing `twins` to `fiveinches` in `area`, because `twins` is undefined)

Comment: Thank you very mutch, but pure of curiosity, is there any possibility of using my way of using two functions?

Comment: Merging the output of two functions is wonky, but possible. Post edited.